# Stop page refresh on Image Button Click

Tags: html, asp.net

This is the code what i tried:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDropArrow" class="cssDropArrow" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Down.gif"  OnClick="ImageDropArrow_Click" runat="server"/>
```

Everytime I click on this imagebutton, page refreshes.

What I want on click is to run the serverside("ImageDropArrow_Click") function and no page refresh.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDropArrow" class="cssDropArrow" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Down.gif"  OnClick="ImageDropArrow_Click" runat="server"/>

Comment: you have to use ajaz in your code

Comment: You can use html button and pagemethods. So server code will execute with no refresh . Also the same thing you can use it with ajax.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `UpdatePanel` in Your Code

for example

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <!--Content Here-->
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDropArrow" class="cssDropArrow" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Down.gif"  OnClick="ImageDropArrow_Click" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following link. It might be helpful for you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/401903/AJAX-for-Beginners-Part-Understanding-ASP-NET-AJ

Answer (score 0):

At first use runat="Server" and you can use updatepanle with imagebutton